# YouTube Data API limits?

Tags: php, api, youtube

Is there a limit to the number of requests I can make with the API? I
see there are limits to uploading and the total number of videos (2000) you can have, but is there a
limit to requests I can make to, for example, the search query
methods?

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Searching_for_videos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this discussion](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=1c1044e7eeb45fe3&hl=en).
Also, you'd want to look at the developer's guide pages regarding [quota errors](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Quota_errors) and [caching data to avoid quota errors](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Caching_data_to_avoid_quota_issues). As you can see there, you will also have a limitation in the number of calls from the same caller in a short amount of time.

Comment: Yes, I posted this information in my question. Looking for more specifics on the data access, not the video upload quota.

Answer (score 2):

[YouTube APIs FAQ: Are there any limits on the number of operations I can perform using the API?](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/faq.html#operation_limits)

> Yes, there is a quota system in place
>   to prevent abuse of the API.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'd love to know what those quotas are though ;) Like "10000 requests per hour"

Comment: Agreed, at least a ballpark would be helpful!