# Youtube API - uploading large file using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, api, youtube

I am trying to upload a large (4MB+) file to youtube using the API in VB.NET.
Smaller files upload fine, but anything larger than about 4MB gives an error which (I think) is actually related to a timeout: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.

I have read and re-read the API doco, googled, etc looking for an example in VB.NET, but nothing seems to be out there for vb.net
A few coders have hit the same problem and the responses have all been around c# or Java - neither of which I am familiar with.
I tried different combinations of the settings.timeout and settings.maximum, but it does not seem to make a difference

Current code is:

Sub UploadYouTube(ByVal sSourceFile As String, ByVal sTitle As String, ByVal sMediaCategory As String, ByVal sDesc As String)
        Dim uSettings As YouTubeRequestSettings, uRequest As YouTubeRequest, newVideo As Video, CreatedVideo As Video, VideoId As String
        Dim vContentType As String = "video"
        Try
            uSettings = New YouTubeRequestSettings(, , , )

```
        uRequest = New YouTubeRequest(uSettings)

        newVideo = New Video()
        newVideo.Title = sTitle '"Test";
        newVideo.Tags.Add(New MediaCategory("Education", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema))
        newVideo.Description = sDesc        '"Testing Testing Testing"
        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = False
        uRequest.Settings.Timeout = 60 * 60 * 1000
        uRequest.Settings.Maximum = 2000000000

        ' Determine the content type
        If sSourceFile.EndsWith(".mov") Then
            vContentType = "video/quicktime"
        ElseIf sSourceFile.EndsWith(".avi") Or sSourceFile.EndsWith(".mpg") Or sSourceFile.EndsWith(".mpeg") Then
            vContentType = "video/mpeg"
        ElseIf sSourceFile.EndsWith(".wmv") Then
            vContentType = "video/x-ms-wmv"
        ElseIf sSourceFile.EndsWith(".m4v") Then
            vContentType = "video/m4v"
        ElseIf sSourceFile.EndsWith(".mp4") Then
            vContentType = "video/mp4"
        ElseIf sSourceFile.EndsWith(".3gp") Then
            vContentType = "video/3gpp"
        End If
        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = New MediaFileSource(sSourceFile, vContentType)

        CreatedVideo = uRequest.Upload(newVideo)
        VideoId = CreatedVideo.VideoId
        ' Save the video Id to the database!
    Catch ex As Exception
        debug.print("Error. MainModule.Main. " & ex.Message, 5)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Tony

Comment: I think its going to be related to quota usage as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676127/youtube-data-api-limits... but the point of my comment is to suggest you dont use File Extensions to work out MIME Types, instead use "Winista" for binary analysis, see my method here that resorts back to URLMon, last answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/d79e76e3-b8c9-4fce-a97d-94ded18ea4dd

Answer (score 0):

Python example : https://github.com/Mathieu69/Pitivi_Gargamel/blob/upload_merger/pitivi/uploader.py did that 3 months ago, hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, but it's a bit obscure to me (no conversant in python)

Comment: the code example I have uploaded just (should) take a file, authenticate and upload. For small files - no problems. Why doesn't it work for larger files?

Comment: I'm not proficient in Vb.net sorry, all I can tell you is that the python gdata youtube API is a pain in the ass. It often changes, meaning you code doesn't work anymore, and the doc is just horrific.

Comment: As I said, I don't know VB.net, but do you absolutely *need* to use it ?

Comment: well - being form VB it makes sense tome to use a tool I am familiar with! This is a small part of a much larger program, and the small team of programmers who look after it are all VB net programmers.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve the timeout problem by using a backgroundworker.  It works, sort of.  It doesn't appear to actually be working in the background.  I would think the RunWorkerAsync would start, move on to the next command, and postback.  Instead it just hangs for a few minutes like it's uploading the whole 75MB file, then posts back successful.  If I take away the backgroundworker and just execute the upload however, it fails like yours did.  Here's my code that kind of works.

```
Sub up_load(s As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker

    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    AddHandler (worker.DoWork), AddressOf begin_upload
    worker.RunWorkerAsync()
    lblmsg.Text = "Successfully initiated upload"
End Sub

Sub begin_upload(s As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)

    Dim request As New YouTubeRequest(settings)
    Dim vidupload As New Video()

    vidupload.Title = "My Big Test Movie"
    vidupload.Tags.Add(New MediaCategory("Nonprofit", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema))
    vidupload.Keywords = "church, jesus"
    vidupload.Description = "See the entire video"
    vidupload.YouTubeEntry.Private = False
    vidupload.YouTubeEntry.setYouTubeExtension("location", "Downers Grove, IL")
    vidupload.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = New MediaFileSource("c:\users\greg\test3.asf", "video/x-ms-wmv")

    Dim createdVideo As Video = Request.Upload(vidupload)
End Sub
```